# References for cascade

Tags: multiple-encryption

I have found many sources against cascading encryption, however I am having trouble finding arguments FOR using cascading.

AES-256 + BlowFish + RC5 etc... each with a different key.

This is for university, so preferably need sources I can reference (so no blog posts unless they are from reputable people).

I also do not need to worry about other weaknesses like dumping RAM, short passwords etc...

Thanks!

Comment: Matthew Green seems reputable to me: http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/02/multiple-encryption.html

Comment: In classical crypto, combining transposition and substitution processing is generally a good idea IMHO.